# Cannot decipher unbalanced body or paragraph tag issue using make4ht

Tags: make4ht

I cannot figure out why make4ht conversion gives a DOM parsing failure.

System: macOS with TeXShop via TeXLive-2022 (all latest versions recently updated)

MWE with all configurations (in case a package conflict is to blame)

```
%% course outline
\DocumentMetadata{uncompress,pdfstandard=a-2u}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%%% PACKAGES
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{ifthen, geometry, hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%% COMMANDS
\newboolean{HTML}
\setboolean{HTML}{false}
\newcommand{\SetHTML}[1][true]{
    \setboolean{HTML}{#1}
    }
\newcommand{\WhenHTML}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{HTML}}
        {#1}{}
        }
%%% COURSE INFO
%%%\input{courseinfo} -- separate file when in use
%%% DOCUMENT SETTINGS
%% page
\geometry{
    letterpaper,
    hmargin={1in,1in},
    vmargin={0.75in,1in},
    headsep=6pt,
    headheight=18pt
    }
%% style
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{4pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
%% hyperref
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={111 The Course},
    pdfsubject={subject},
    pdfkeywords={keywords},
    pdfauthor={author},
    pdflang={en-US},
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue
    }
%%% DOCUMENT
\begin{document}

%% output ToC in HTML mode
\WhenHTML{\tableofcontents}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}{\LARGE{}111: The Course}\end{center}

\section{Course Information}

\subsection{Contact}

\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\rule{0.95\textwidth}{0pt}} \\
\textbf{Instructor}: Instructor
& \textbf{Office}: Office \\
\textbf{Email}: \href{mailto:somewhere@someplace.edu}{somewhere@someplace.edu} &
\textbf{Phone}: 111-222-3333 \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Office Hours}: by appointment} \\
\end{tabular}

\subsection{Details}

\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\rule{0.95\textwidth}{0pt}} \\
\textbf{Course Name}: The Course
& \textbf{Delivery Mode}: in person \\
\textbf{Credit Hours}: 3 &
\textbf{Semester/Year}: Fall 2022 \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Meeting}: at some time, somewhere}
\end{tabular}

\textbf{Prerequisites}: some things you must know before you start

\subsection{Overview}

\subsubsection{Catalogue Description}

\subsubsection{Description}

\lipsum[1]

\section{University Information}

Refer to information posted under the Syllabus link for the course.

\end{document}
```

The document compiles via LaTeX to PDF.

I am compiling to HTML via an engine with this command line

```
make4ht -u -c syllabus.cfg -d Webpage $1
```

Elements in the css file are akin to

```
/* start css.sty */
body{
    font-size:100%;
    }
.likesectionHead{
    font-size:5vw;
    color:blue;
    }
table{
    width:100%;
    }
/* end css.sty */
```

The cfg file is

```
\Preamble{xhmtl}
% top
\Configure{VERSION}{} 
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>}} 
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{\Hnewline<html>}}{\HCode{</html>}}
\Configure{AddCss}{syllabus.css}
% header
\Configure{HEAD}{\HCode{\Hnewline<head>}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</head>}}
\Configure{TITLE+}{Course Outline} 
\Configure{@HEAD}{}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\Hnewline<meta  charset="utf-8"/>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\Hnewline<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\Hnewline<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="syllabus.css"/>}}
% body
\Configure{BODY}{\HCode{\Hnewline<body>}}{\HCode{</body>\Hnewline}} 
% paragraphs
\Configure{HtmlPar}
    {\EndP\HCode{\Hnewline<p class="indent">}}{\EndP\HCode{\Hnewline<p class="noindent">}}
    {\HCode{</p>}}{\HCode{</p>}}
% Translate \textbf, \textit and \texttt directives into <strong>, <em> and <code> 
\Configure{emph}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<em>}}{\HCode{</em>}} 
\Configure{textbf}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<strong>}}{\HCode{</strong>}} 
\Configure{textit}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<em>}}{\HCode{</em>}} 
\Configure{texttt}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<code>}}{\HCode{</code>}} 
\Configure{textsc}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<span class="sc">}}{\HCode{</span>}} 
\begin{document}
% \Configure{FontFamily}{rmfamily}{Latin Modern}
\SetHTML{}
\EndPreamble
```

The compilation message is

```
[37m[STATUS]  [0mmake4ht: Conversion started
[37m[STATUS]  [0mmake4ht: Input file: courseoutline.tex
[33m[WARNING] [0mdomfilter: DOM parsing of courseoutline.html failed:
[33m[WARNING] [0mdomfilter: ...ive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/body) [char=6707]

[37m[STATUS]  [0mmake4ht: Conversion finished
```

The HTML file is missing a closing </p>

```
<p class="indent">Refer to information posted under the Syllabus link for the course.
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't close paragraphs in your `body` configuration. When you want to insert tags which should close the current paragraph, and which shouldn't be included in any paragraphs, such as `</body>`, you need to use the `\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP` commands. The `\IgnorePar` will prevent insertion of the new `<p>` tag, and `\EndP` will insert closing `</p>`.

So the correct configuration file could look like this:

```
\Preamble{xthml}
% top
\Configure{VERSION}{} 
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>}} 
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{\Hnewline<html>}}{\HCode{</html>}}
\Configure{AddCss}{syllabus.css}
% header
\Configure{HEAD}{\HCode{\Hnewline<head>}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</head>}}
\Configure{TITLE+}{Course Outline} 
\Configure{@HEAD}{}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\Hnewline<meta  charset="utf-8"/>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\Hnewline<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\Hnewline<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="syllabus.css"/>}}
% body
\Configure{BODY}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{\Hnewline<body>}}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</body>\Hnewline}} 
% paragraphs
\Configure{HtmlPar}
    {\EndP\HCode{\Hnewline<p class="indent">}}{\EndP\HCode{\Hnewline<p class="noindent">}}
    {\HCode{</p>}}{\HCode{</p>}}
% Translate \textbf, \textit and \texttt directives into <strong>, <em> and <code> 
\Configure{emph}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<em>}}{\HCode{</em>}} 
\Configure{textbf}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<strong>}}{\HCode{</strong>}} 
\Configure{textit}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<em>}}{\HCode{</em>}} 
\Configure{texttt}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<code>}}{\HCode{</code>}} 
\Configure{textsc}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<span class="sc">}}{\HCode{</span>}} 
\begin{document}
% \Configure{FontFamily}{rmfamily}{Latin Modern}
\SetHTML{}
\EndPreamble
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. My approach to the cfg likely reveals an engineer who hacked together various parts scattered on the Web. I would never have recognized that this addition is needed, and I lack the deeper understanding to have puzzled it out on my own. FWIW, I had hacked a work-around that simply substituted `{\HCode{</p>\Hnewline</body>\Hnewline}}` as the closing code for `\Configure{BODY}`. All is good now!

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer sure, it is a normal approach, as there is a lot of information scattered around the web. Lately, I've put lot of actual information to the documentation here:  https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Configurations.html